# How to alter catalog_product_flat column types

Tags: product, database, catalog, magento-1, indexing

A website I manage requires prices to have 5 decimals. I went ahead and modified at least a dozen file/tables altogether to be able to achieve this. But ('cause there's always a but) there seems to be a problem with `catalog_product_flat_X`.

Let me explain : for prices on the front, most of the time, it's come down to calling `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->getPrice()`, which, as I understand it, will look for the price in the flat tables (if you have flat tables enabled). The issue is with the reindexing of data.

If my flat table has a price with the format `DECIMAL(12,5)`, hitting the "Reindex" link on the "Reindex flat data" line will `ALTER` the flat table and put it back to `DECIMAL(12,4)`.

After searching for quite an extented amount of time, I came accros a function in
`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php`
which is called `prepareFlatTable($storeId)`. This function then calls `convertOldColumnDefinition($column)` on every column of the flat table (in this case).

Finally, when looking at this function in
`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Helper/Abstract.php`
it seems to be converting every `decimal` and `numeric` like so :

```
case 'decimal':
case 'numeric':
        $length = $proposedLength;
        $type = Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL;
        break;
```

in which `$proposedLength` is the result of this :

```
$definition = trim($column['type']);
if (!preg_match('/([^(]*)(\\((.*)\\))?/', $definition, $matches)) {
    throw Mage::exception(
        'Mage_Core',
        Mage::helper('core')->__("Wrong old style column type definition: {$definition}.")
    );
}

$proposedLength = (isset($matches[3]) && strlen($matches[3])) ? $matches[3] : null;
```

I don't quite understand what's going on here, I'd put something hardcoded in there but I don't want to interfere with the normal process of all the indexers.

Can anyone enlighten me on this matter and offer me a solution?

Comment: can you please post the solution? What did you change in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Helper/Abstract.php` file? I have the same issue and I can't find a solution

Comment: @zekia I honestly can't remember sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you some explanation about the code that converts the column definition:

```
    $definition = trim($column['type']);
    if (!preg_match('/([^(]*)(\\((.*)\\))?/', $definition, $matches)) {
        throw Mage::exception(
            'Mage_Core',
            Mage::helper('core')->__("Wrong old style column type definition: {$definition}.")
        );
    }
```

So basically the `preg_match` method will give you an array in the `$matches` variable based on the column definition (stored in `$definition`).

Example of columns definition usually looks like this:

- int
- varchar(100)
- decimal(12,4)

Those column definitions will respectively give you the following result in the `$matches` array:

- `array('int','int')`
- `array('varchar(100)','varchar','(100)','100')`
- `array('decimal(12,4)','decimal','(12,4)','12,4')`

Then you've got the `$proposedLength` variable:

$proposedLength = (isset($matches[3]) && strlen($matches[3])) ? $matches[3] : null;

It is basically equal to the 4th entry in the `$matches` array if this one is set.

So in your case the value of the `$proposeLength` should be `12,5`.

My suggestion:

Add the following code right after the `$proposedLength` variable declaration:

```
Mage::log($column);
Mage::log($matches);
Mage::log($proposedLength);
```

Try again and check your `var/log/system.log` file to ensure that the code behaves like it should.

Comment: @fschmengler edited the title of my question, which is now misleading because it doesn't match what I wanted to ask in my question.
I ended up hardcoding a value in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Helper/Abstract.php` .

Comment: @JulienLachal feel free to post your solution and mark your question as answered

Comment: Nah, it's not a solution, it's a hack, so I won't post it. I think I'll accept your as it details what's supposed to happen.